# Get date ranges

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects -

```
[
{ name:'abc',
  lRange: '2020-01-01',
  hRange: '2020-01-22',
},

{ name:'abc',
  lRange: '2020-01-01',
  hRange: '2020-01-22',
},
{ name:'def',
  lRange: '2020-01-15',
  hRange: '2020-01-30',
},
{ name:'ghi',
  lRange: '2020-02-10',
  hRange: '2020-02-22',
}
]
```

I need to get the min Date and Max Date range combining all the dates lRange and hRange dates - there will be a overlap of the dates too.

I have tried sorting by date times but that is not giving me the correct range. any ideaS?

Comment: Show us your approach please

Comment: So you are looking for the lowest lrange and highest hrange?

Comment: yes I need lowest lrange and highest hrange

Comment: So what's the problem? loop all elements in array and find lowest and highest values by comparing them in each iteration

Comment: You can reduce into an object w. lrange and hrange and in every cycle compare your stored lrange and hrange with the current. Create date objects for easy comparison (https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/4410144).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, though I suspect there are more elegant methods. It converts each string date into a date object and compares them. Finally it takes the min and max and converts them back into readable strings.

```js
let dates = [{
    name: 'abc',
    lRange: '2019-02-01',
    hRange: '2020-01-22',
  },

  {
    name: 'abc',
    lRange: '2020-01-01',
    hRange: '2020-01-22',
  },
  {
    name: 'def',
    lRange: '2020-01-15',
    hRange: '2020-01-30',
  },
  {
    name: 'ghi',
    lRange: '2020-02-10',
    hRange: '2020-02-22',
  }
]

let output = {}

dates.forEach(obj => {
  if (!output.min) {
    output.min = new Date(obj.lRange);
    output.max = new Date(obj.hRange);
  } else {
    output.min = Math.min(output.min, new Date(obj.lRange))

    output.max = Math.max(output.max, new Date(obj.hRange))

  }

})
//convert back to date strings
 output.min =  new Date(output.min).toISOString().split("T")[0]
 output.max =  new Date(output.max).toISOString().split("T")[0]

 console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get all dates and then sort it. After sorting the first element (i.e element at index `0`) is minRange and element at last index is maxRange.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "abc", lRange: "2020-01-01", hRange: "2020-01-22" },
  { name: "abc", lRange: "2020-01-01", hRange: "2020-01-22" },
  { name: "def", lRange: "2020-01-15", hRange: "2020-01-30" },
  { name: "ghi", lRange: "2020-02-10", hRange: "2020-02-22" },
];

const sortedResult = arr
  .flatMap((obj) => [obj.lRange, obj.hRange])
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));

const result = {
  min: sortedResult[0],
  max: sortedResult[sortedResult.length - 1],
};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the lRagnes and hRanges out into individual arrays if it makes it easier for you.

```
var lDates = [];
var hDates = [];

yourArray.map((innerObjects) => {
    lDates .push(innerObjects.lRange);
    hDates .push(innerObjects.hRange);
});
```